# How to add up total cost of basket?

Tags: java, shopping-cart

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mercadona");
    System.out.println("-----Mercadona Menu----");
    System.out.println("| 1. Milk £1          |");
    System.out.println("| 2. Eggs £2.50       |");
    System.out.println("| 3. Bread £1.20      |");
    System.out.println("| 4. Sugar £2         |");
    System.out.println("| 5. Toothpaste £3.50 |");
    System.out.println("| 6. Toothbrush £10   |");
    System.out.println("| 7. Birthday Cake £50|");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    System.out.println("Minimum order of 3 products");

    System.out.println("Maximum order of 4 products");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Enter product");

    String product=input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter quantity");

    int quantity=input.nextInt();  
    
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Enter product");

    String product2=input2.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter quantity");

    int quantity2=input2.nextInt();  

    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Enter product");

    String product3=input3.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter quantity");

    int quantity3=input3.nextInt();  
    
    System.out.println("You have reached minimum order limit.");

    System.out.println(" Would you like to continue ordering?");

    System.out.println("Choose number 90 for yes and number 100 for no");
  
   Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in); 

   System.out.println("Enter number");
   
   int y = input4.nextInt();

   System.out.println(y);

   if (y == 90 ) {

   System.out.println("You can continue shopping.");

   Scanner input5 = new Scanner(System.in); 

   System.out.println("Enter product");

   String product5=input5.nextLine();
    
   System.out.println("Enter quantity");

   int quantity5=input5.nextInt();  
   
   } else if (y == 100) {

   System.out.println("Your order basket is complete");


   //now to calculate cost of order basket//
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So, if you type `"1"`, how are you going to know that that is "Milk" or how much it costs? Seems like you should be storing that infomation in order to add anything

Comment: how would i store that information :S

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can think of, without adding arrays or anything, would to just have a double called basket that just has a running total. After each item, do this:

```
if (product.equalsIgnoreCase("milk")) basket += 1*quantity;
else if (product.equalsIgnoreCase("eggs")) basket += 2.5*quantity;
//add else ifs for each product, and the basket just does += price*quantity for each product
```

Also, side note, the code will run much more smoothly if you don't use so many scanners. The computer can really only handle one instance of System.in nicely, and the scanner can be used infinitely until you type `input.close()`, so just keep using input.

Another way to up efficiency would be to use the same product and quantity variables the whole time. Since you are always updating the basket, you can just change the same variables to avoid clogging memory.

Answer (score -1):

You can do probably something like that.

```
public class main {
    


      public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to Mercadona");
            System.out.println("-----Mercadona Menu----");
            System.out.println("| 1. Milk £1          |");
            System.out.println("| 2. Eggs £2.50       |");
            System.out.println("| 3. Bread £1.20      |");
            System.out.println("| 4. Sugar £2         |");
            System.out.println("| 5. Toothpaste £3.50 |");
            System.out.println("| 6. Toothbrush £10   |");
            System.out.println("| 7. Birthday Cake £50|");
            System.out.println("-----------------------");

            System.out.println("Minimum order of 3 products");

            System.out.println("Maximum order of 4 products");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

            System.out.println("Enter product");

            String product=input.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Enter quantity");

            int quantity=input.nextInt();  
            
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in); 

            System.out.println("Enter product");

            String product2=input2.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Enter quantity");

            int quantity2=input2.nextInt();  

            Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in); 

            System.out.println("Enter product");

            String product3=input3.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Enter quantity");

            int quantity3=input3.nextInt();  
            
            System.out.println("You have reached minimum order limit.");

            System.out.println(" Would you like to continue ordering?");

            System.out.println("Choose number 90 for yes and number 100 for no");
          
           Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in); 

           System.out.println("Enter number");
           
           int y = input4.nextInt();

           System.out.println(y);

           int quantity5 = 0;
           
           if (y == 90 ) {

           System.out.println("You can continue shopping.");

           Scanner input5 = new Scanner(System.in); 

           System.out.println("Enter product");

           String product5=input5.nextLine();
            
           System.out.println("Enter quantity");

           quantity5=input5.nextInt();  
           
           } else if (y == 100) {

           System.out.println("Your order basket is complete");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           
           int total_quantity = quantity + quantity2 + quantity3;
           
           int total_quantity_after_number_90 = 0;
           
           if( y == 90 )
           total_quantity_after_number_90 = total_quantity + quantity5;
         
    }

  }

}
```